# Transparent png texture in cocos2d using opengl iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, transparent

I am creating a polygon filled with texture using opengl in cocos2d framework. I have used PRKit([link](https://github.com/asinesio/cocos2d-PRKit)) and modified the draw method with the code shown below.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture.name);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, polyTriangulatedPoints);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureCoordinates);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, trianglePointCount);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

When I use transparent png as texture I get a bit weird result. The transparent area is not black, but some random colors with black. Here is the output I get with the above code.

[image: transparent png]

I had to keep glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO) which is same as disabling blending. If I don't do so, my background layer in cocos2d gets added with my texture image resulting in a very bright looking texture. To add more information, I have set texture mode so that all images are loaded with the following.

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

My question is that why do I see this kind of random colors in transparent area and what are the ways to solve this? I have a feeling that I must be doing something wrong since I am new to opengl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a texture with full opaque / full transparent pixel (alpha = 1.0 or 0.0 only), you can keep GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA to keep the transparency.

Else you can use alpha test with GL_GREATER, 0.0 (or discard keyword in fragment shader if you use opengl es 2.0).

But on ios, alpha test is less performant than alpha blending.

Comment: I am not sure how to use this information to solve my problem as I am not experienced in opengl, but I will have a look at GL_GREATER and do some experiments. Thank you for taking time to reply.

Comment: if you use opengl es 1.1, you can add these commands before your glDrawArrays :

glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.0f);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

Comment: Ah I see. I am running this code on iPhone simulator right now, so I am not sure what version of opengl it is actually using. But I will give this a try and see how it works. Thanks :)

Comment: If you use cocos2d, it's normally opengl es 1.1 so you are free to use glAlphaFunc